# Node.JS :Puppeteer Multithread Instance with multiple different Socks5 Problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, loops, puppeteer

I wrote a function start() for Puppeteer which starts one Browserinstance with an Proxy. I provie the proxy from a Array called socks. The code looks like that:

```
async function start() {
      let launchOption = {
      headless: false,
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--proxy-server=socks5://" + socks[0],};

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOption);
      const page = await brower.newPage();
      await page.goto("https://example.com");
       }
```

Now i want to start multiple Browsers, each with a different socks. For example:

browser1 = "--proxy-server=socks5://" + socks[0]
browser2 = "--proxy-server=socks5://" + socks[1]
....

I want to do that, without creating multiple functions where i would change the Sock. I was thinking about a loop, but i dont really know how to put it all together. If somebody would be so kind and put me into the direction where to start i would be really thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely go with loop. 
Just use some wait functions run it properly.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    start(i); 
}
```

This opens 10 browser at the same time.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    await start(i); 
}
```

This opens 10 browser one by one after load.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    start(i); 
    wait(3000);
}

function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

This opens your browser every 3 seconds.

Regards

Comment: hey iguru, thanks for your answer. that looks sweet! So the best way would be to write the socks in a config.json and require it i think. But how to loop everything that the second browser gets the next ip?

Like this: browser0 = socks[0}
  browser1 = socks[1]
....

Thanks for your help!

Comment: const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOption); This command let you open new browser with new sockets I think

Comment: I think my English is not good enough to understand your sentences correctly. If you can describe me again, it will be pleasure.

Comment: of course :) So i want to open for example 5 browsers, but each with a different Socks5. So i dont know how to use a loop poperly within the object launchoption for the variable socks.

Comment: async function start(index) {
      let launchOption = {
      headless: false,
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--proxy-server=socks5://" + socks[index],};

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOption);
      const page = await brower.newPage();
      await page.goto("https://example.com");
       } This will get you 5 browser with 5 sockets if you call the functions with loop. Hopes this help you